# how to create dynamic link labels in window form application

Tags: c#, winforms, events

On clicking Go button the name given in textbox should be displayed as a link label and this should increment dynamically.

Here my code:

```
private void buttongo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   linkLabelName.Text = textBoxName.Text;               
}
```

Comment: I do not have understood everything. You want "linkLabelName" change dynamically with the text of "textBoxName" without needing to click on the button "buttongo" ?

Comment: No i want to display the names given in the textbox as linklabels in the panel...can u help me??

Comment: Why do you want to use link label?

Comment: After displaying the names in the textbox as link labels and on clicking the link label a new window form should be opened.This is my basic requirement..

Comment: I would use a listbox, there you have more control over the data. you can just use the listbox events that best suits you

Comment: U mean to say that i need to use listbox instead of Panel??

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void btnGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LinkLabel link = new LinkLabel();
            link.Text = txtText.Text;
            panTable.Controls.Add(link);
        }
```

Comment: This code is not working....I don't know why?? Here PanTable refers to panel control.but no linklabel is created on clicking Go button

Comment: private System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel panTable;